# Is there proof that the exact exchange correlation functional is an analytic function?

Tags: computational-chemistry, density-functional-theory

Mathematics show that some problems cannot be solved analytically. Could this be true for the exact exchange correlation functional?

Most textbooks state that the form of the exact exchange correlation functional is unknown. It is said to be an unknown mathematical object. Does this mean that said functional is an analytical function? And if so, what is the proof that shows that the functional is analytical?

Comment: What do you mean by analytic?

Comment: Then I think the answer is no, since there is derivative discontinuity for the exact functional.

Comment: @user26143 Sorry. I meant this one: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Analytic.html
Not: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function

Comment: I guess the answer depends on the scope of "known functions". If we restrict to the elementary functions, most likely it is not (I do NOT know any PROOF for this point). It has been shown finding exact functional is NP-hard problem, e.g. http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v5/n10/full/nphys1415.html

Answer (score 1):

See my colleagues work, it seems to be the answer you want.

http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.93.042511

Comment: Welcome to Chem.SE - thanks for posting! It's [site policy](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to include more description in answers than just a link to an external resource -- can you edit your answer to include a summary of their results/conclusions? As well, if you haven't already, please check out the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) pages for more information. Enjoy!

Comment: This could be a valuable answer, so I encourage you to expound on it as the users above have suggested.